Action of an algebraic group $G$ on a scheme $X$ with fixed rational point
Let $X$ be an irreducible locally noetherian $k$-scheme ($k$ any field) and $G$ an algebraic $k$-group acting on $X$.
Proposition 3.1.6 in these notes by M. Brion claims

Let $a : G \times X \to X$ be an action of an algebraic group on an irreducible locally noetherian scheme and let $x \in X(k)$. Then the quotient group scheme $C_G(x)/\text{Ker}(a)$ (quotient of centralizer) is affine.

The proof easily reduces to the case $G=C_G(x)$ and hence that $x \in X(k)$ is fixed by $G$. Let's consider in the following also only this case and so specialize the previous claim to:

Let $a : G \times X \to X$ be an action as before and let $x \in X(k)$ be fixed by $G$. Then $G$ is affine.

which Brion after the remarked reduction step actually proves.
Rmk.: This is actually also the statement of Prop. 8.9 in Milne's Algebraic Groups
The both proofs mainly use the observation that as $G$ assumed to fix $x$, the $G$-action induces to an action on the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and consequently on infinitesimal neighborhoods $x_{(n)}:=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/ \mathfrak{m}_x^n)$ and so forth deriving at the end that certain fixed subscheme $X^H \subset X$ must be already whole $X$, giving at the end that $G$ embeds as closed immersion in appropr $\text{GL}_m$.
Question: Why it is neccessary for the given proofs to assume the closed fixed point $x$ by $G$ to be rational, ie $x \in X(k)$, and so in turn why it cannot be for example a closed $L$- valued point $x \in X(L)$ for some finite field extension $k \subset L$?
(EDIT #1: Note that $L$ has to be finite (equivalently by Zariski's lemma that $x$ is closed in $X$ in topol. sense) is nessessary as the proof proceeds by constructing finite dimnl reps over $k$ of local rings   $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/ \mathfrak{m}_x^n$. So as @Dave Benson pointed out that eg $x$ choosen to be the generic point runs the proof mechanism there badly into troubles as the proof's strategy there includes producing only finite dimensional $k$-reps.
In other words, where precisely the argumentation of the presented proofs would break down if $x$ would not be rational?
If I'm not missing something going through the presented proof, then assuming this the $G$ action would still descend to the induced action on infinitelimal neighborhoods of $x$, and also all other steps in the proof seemingly nowhere exploit to rationality $x$, so seemingly the proof would still go through for a nonrational fixed point, or not?
So I not understand where we really need unavoidably that the fixed point $x$ was assumed to be rational.
EDIT #2: As LSpice pointed out to prove the claim as it is stated there it indeed suffice to assume that the fixed point is rational applying fppf descent (...affiness can be checked on fppf cover), so by base changing if neccessarily it suffice to treat the case that the fixed point is $k$-rational.
But as I emphsised in the comments my question is primary about the "legitimation" of the "methods/techniques" of the given proof depending on $x$ is rational or not. Essentially, the leading question should be phrased as that what if the fixed closed point $x$ is not rational, but we still carry out "literally with head trought the wall" the same argumentation as Brion resp. Milne gave in the notes except that $x$ is not rational?
Then,  which steps precisely in the proof mechanism would fail or even cannot be conducted or even phrased?
Maybe following LSpice's comments the problem is also that certain constructions used there have no meaning when $x$ is not rational.
But I not sure if that's the case, probably I misunderstood LSpice's point below in the comments.
Let me try to elaborate it in  more details, maybe this reveals also what not understood. If closed $x$ is fixed by $G$, then formally by "the action on the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/ \mathfrak{m}_x^n$ should be formulated in terms of point functors namely as map $G \to \operatorname{Aut}_k(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/ \mathfrak{m}_x^n)$ defined for every fin. gen. $k$-algebra $R$ by group homomorphism $G(R) \to \operatorname{Aut}(R \otimes_k (\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/ \mathfrak{m}_x^n)$.
Intermediate question: Is it at the stage neccessary that $x$ is rational in order that this action is well defined? I not see here any problem but maybe that's exactly the problematic step.
So the question is if there is something "fishy" with this functor if $x$ would be not rational?
EDIT #3: above appears also a potential notation problem/ notation abusion with stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ for $x \in X(L)$ non rational: keeping the notation precise by the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is actually meant the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,\mathfrak{m}_x}$ which is as usually formed by localizing appropr ring $R$ corresponding to an affine chart of $X$ containing image of $x$ at (maximal) prime $\mathfrak{m}_x$ be the kernel of $x^*: R \to L$ corresponding to $x$.

Have you tried following the argument through for the generic point of an irreducible scheme with a faithful action of a non-affine algebraic group?

@DaveBenson: That's goes to become "very" pathologically. As intermediate state in the proof we want to construct "finite (!)dimensional" reps via actions of $G$ on infinitelimal thickierings $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/ \mathfrak{m}_x^n$. If $x$ would be the generic point then two pathologies happen: firstly all these rings would be the same (as then max ideal $m_x=0$) and even more dramatically these local rings would be infinitely dimensional as vspaces over $k$, but we want to construct finite dimensional $k$-reps.

@DaveBenson: So my question was badly posed: One should alk what about $L$-valued points $x \in X(L)$ with $L$ finite over $k$. Thanks for pointing that out!

Or do you see a reason why the quoted argument even for fixed closed $x \in X(L)-X(k)$ with $L$ finite, but non trivial extensions of $k$ would break down?

Affineness descends along fppf extensions, so, if $G$ defined over $k$ becomes affine over a finite field extension $L/k$, then it is affine over $k$.

@LSpice: Right, that's a good point, so to derive the claim using your fppf descent argument we can wlog assume the existence of rational fixed point after passing to approp field extension. But my concern is focused here more on the "mechanism" of the presented proof by Brion resp Milne. What I'm wondering above is if and where the concrete given "proof mechanism" would potentially  fail if we don't assume $x$ rational. Would "the same proof" literally really plainly go through independently $x$ is rational or not.

Re, I'd argue not so much that the argument goes wrong, but that it can't even be phrased—just as it is in some sense illegitimate to speak of eigenvalues of $\begin{pmatrix} & 1 \ -1 \end{pmatrix}$ on $\mathbb R^2$, and we must go to $\mathbb C^2$ before finding any, similarly $G$ itself does not act in any sensible way on $\mathscr O_{X, x}$ (in fact $\mathscr O_{X, x}$ itself doesn't make sense!), and only $G_L$ acts on $\mathscr O_{X_L, x}$.

@LSpice: That maybe hits exactly the point I was missing. Why,if $x$ is not rational, $G$ may not act in "sensible"/reasonable way on the local ring $\mathcal{O}{X,x}$ (resp it's quotients by $m_x^n$). Note that the induced action is precisely formulated in terms of point functors, namely by $G(R) \to \text{Aut}(R \otimes_k(\mathcal{O}{X,x}/m_x^n))$  for fin gen $k$-algebras $R$ (cpre with Milne's notations, p 150)

@LSpice: Or, what do you mean that then this action on $O_{X,x}$ would "not make sense" for non rational $x$?

@LSpice: Just to avoid confusions: Is in your last comment the object $G_L$ (acting on $O_{X_L,x}$) the "scheme"/ $G \otimes_k L$ / ( ...equiv'lently point functor $(L-alg) \to $(Grps) )or abstract group $(G \otimes L)(L)$ (ie after evaluated the point functor in $L$)

@LSpice: An Update: Pondering about your comment and the issue that not assuming rationality might give non well defined action reminded me coarsly a bit on the problem with well posedness of a point functor as discussed here recently.. Maybe if $x$ is not rational something with naturality of the natural trafo of the point functors in penultimate comment goes wrong, but I still haven't found an example

Yes, $G_L$ is the base change of $G$ to $L$, not the group of $L$-rational points. I was saying that it doesn't make sense to speak of $\mathscr O_{X, x}$ any more than it does to speak of $\mathscr O_{\mathbb A_{\mathbb R}, i}$, but, for $L/k$ separable, I guess you can identify $x$ with the kernel of the associated homomorphism $k[X] \to L$; and inseparable extensions can be handled by applying a suitable power of Frobenius. With these provisions, I don't know if the argument works, but I guess that Brion states the argument as he does just for concreteness, and because it doesn't matter.

@LSpice: Thanks for clarification, now I see what you mean, I should have been precise as I have indeed it badly phrased. Indeed using your example if say $x:\mathbb{R}[T] \to \mathbb{C}, X \mapsto i$ so is a member of $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{C})$, then we can naturally associate the kernel $\mathfrak{m}x \subset \mathbb{R}[T] $ of this map (a ( maximal) prime) and consider the stalk at $m_x$. And so coming back to general case the question becomes if $x \in X(L)$ is fixed by $G$ action,does this action descend to $k$- linear action on stalk $\mathcal{O}{X, m_x}$ and

it's infinitesimal quotients by powers of $\mathfrak{m}_x$ and how nontriviality of $L/k$ could potentially make some steps in presented proofs unvalid.
